# NLTK gives error expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, text, nlp, nltk

I imported a dataset (.csv) with pandas. The first column is the column with tweets, I rename it and transform it to a numpy array as usual with .values. Then I start the pre-processing with NLTK, it works pretty much every time, except for this dataset. It gives me the error TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object and I can't figure out why. The text contains some weird stuff, but far from the worst I've seen. Can someone help out?

```
data = pd.read_csv("facebook.csv")
text = data["Anonymized Message"].values

X = []
for i in range(0, len(text)):
    tweet = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", text[i])
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    tweet = tweet.split()
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    tweet = [ps.stem(word) for word in tweet if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    tweet = ' '.join(tweet)
    X.append(tweet)
```

gives me this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-a08c1779c787> in <module>()
      1 text_train = []
      2 for i in range(0, len(text)):
----> 3     tweet = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", text[i])
      4     tweet = tweet.lower()
      5     tweet = tweet.split()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    189     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    190     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 191     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    192 
    193 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Here's the dataset
http://wwbp.org/downloads/public_data/dataset-fb-valence-arousal-anon.csv

Comment: can you please post what you are taking into text

Comment: yes, sorry, should've done that right away

Comment: Hey, are you sure the data is the same one in the link? because it doesn't have anything called tweets.

Comment: Probably a NaN or some non-string value. Set it to print() the tweet before trying to regex it, and you will see what the value is before it fails. Or just use your debugger.